# Data read through socket on a remote server is empty

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-ec2

We have a client-server software made in java.

Client part sends a string:

```
dataOutputStream.writeUTF("User");
```

Server reads this string:

```
String login = dataInputStream.readUTF();
System.out.println("User accepted: " + login);
```

The server part is launched on amazon ec2.
We have 2 offices and from 1 office everything works fine:
server accepts the socket and read the data correctly,
but from another office the server accepts the socket, however reads empty strings.

All the ports are opened for our IPs in the EC2 control panel.

I have installed WireShark and checked if correct data goes to the server and yes, it is correct.

Both offices are running the same client part.
The only difference i know is that office 1 have Win 7 and 8 (works on both, tried different machines) and office 2 have Win 10 (doesn't work, tried different machines)

What could be the reason of such behavior? What we could check / try to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

`DataInputStream.readUTF()` cannot possibly return an empty `String`, by which I assume you mean a `String` object whose `length()` is zero, unless an empty string was presented to `writeUTF()` at the other end. It can however throw an `EOFException` if the data has somehow been truncated in flight.

You'll have to post some code to elucidate this further.

Comment: it doesn't throw any exceptions, we actually send 2 strings, and 100% client sends them not empty, but sysout shows both strings are empty. I can also try to trace lengths of the strings. I will post the result soon.

Comment: And please, keep in mind, that the same client code, which sends the same data works from other office!

Comment: Traced length. It is 0 for both strings. So we send 2 not empty strings "User" and "Project" and the server reads them as empty strings without any errors. Here is the server code: 
String login = dataInputStream.readUTF();
String project = dataInputStream.readUTF();
System.out.println("User accepted: " + login + " (Project: " + project + ")");
System.out.println("Login len: " + login.length() + " Project len: " + project.length() + ")");

And here is the result:
User accepted:  (Project: )
Login len: 0 Project len: 0)

Comment: Don't post code in comments. I can't read that, and I doubt that you can either. Edit it into your question. And include the writing code and the code that sets up both the `DataInputStream` and the `DataOutputStream.`

Comment: Ok, I won't, but can't edit my comment anymore. The code above is not important, the main message is YES, THE LENGH is 0